# Spark - Scala : Return multiple <key, value> after processing one line

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that looks like below -

0 -- 1,2,4 
1 -- 0,4 
2 -- 0,4 
4 -- 2,1,0

I want to read each line and transform it to something that looks like below

// for the line 0 -- 1,2,4 
(0,1) <2,4> 
(0,2) <1,4> 
(0,4) <1,2>

// for the line 1 -- 0,4 
(0,1) <4> 
(1,4) <0>

// smaller number appeears first in the pair always

i.e., read each line separated on "--" delimiter. So I get 0 and 1,2,4 from line 1 of the dataset. After that, I want create pairs. For example, (0,1) which will be the key for the transformed map and its value should be 2,4.

Once this is done, I want to be able to group values by key

For example (0,1) <2,4> <4>

and intersect them to get 4.

Is it possible to do something like this? Is my approach right?

I have written the below code so far-

```
var mapOperation = logData.map(x=>x.split("\t")).filter(x => x.length == 2).map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
// reading file and creating the map Example - key 0 value 1,2,4

//from the first map, trying to create pairs
var mapAgainstValue = mapOperation.map{
line =>
val fromFriend = line._1
val toFriendsList = line._2.split(",")
(fromFriend -> toFriendsList)
}

val newMap = mapAgainstValue.map{
line =>
var key ="";
for(userIds <- line._2){
key =line._1.concat(","+userIds);
(key -> line._2.toList)
}

}
```

The problem is I am not able to call groupByKey on newMap. I am assuming there is some issue with the way I have created the map?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question and add some more detail as I am not able to figure out what you actuallly want

Comment: I edited the question. Hope its better than before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be solved like this :

```
 val inputRDD=sc.textFile("inputFile.txt")  
inputRDD.flatMap{a=>
          val list=a.split("--")
          val firstTerm=list(0)
          val secondTermAsList=list(1).split(",")
          secondTermAsList.map{b=>
          val key=if(b>firstTerm) (firstTerm,b) else (b,firstTerm)
          val value=secondTermAsList diff List(b)
          (key,value)
          }
          }
```

This code results in this output :

```
+-----+------+
|_1   |_2    |
+-----+------+
|[0,1]|[2, 4]|
|[0,2]|[1, 4]|
|[0,4]|[1, 2]|
|[0,1]|[4]   |
|[1,4]|[0]   |
|[0,2]|[4]   |
|[2,4]|[0]   |
|[2,4]|[1, 0]|
|[1,4]|[2, 0]|
|[0,4]|[2, 1]|
+-----+------+
```

I hope this solves your issue !

Comment: That is real good piece of code. Thanks a lot. So, from here I should be able to do a group by key and intersect the value sets.

Comment: Just one more thing, where should I add the filter if not every element in the dataset has values after the delimiter -- ?

Comment: Check if list size after separation is 1 . If it is just give the default Value or else do the computation

Comment: I am unable to add an if condition like this -                                           val x = inputRDD.flatMap { a =>
      val list = a.split("\t")
      if (list.length > 1) {
        val firstTerm = list(0)
        val secondTermAsList = list(1).split(",")
        secondTermAsList.map { b =>
          val key = if (b.toInt > firstTerm.toInt) (firstTerm, b) else (b, firstTerm)
          val value = secondTermAsList diff List(b)
          (key, value)
        }
      }
    }

Comment: You have to evaluate if as an expression

Comment: Can you give an example? I am evaluating the length. Can't I execute the block if the evaluation returns true?